# Focus URL in Firefox - 100% guaranteed way

Tags: firefox, flash, url, focus

How can I guaranteed, 100% ,absolutely etc. focus URL in Firefox browser?

If there is Flash on page that focus is on it and CTR-L doesn't focus URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, the Flash portion is another application which handles all of your hot-keys (even tab switching).

To guarantee you need to use your mouse to click outside the flash element. The only reasonable surround I can see is to use AutoHotkey to emulate a mouse click so it can be done by keyboard...

Comment: yes, I know and do redundant click, how it's frustrating,I just want ctr-l to focus URL

Comment: @sergionni: Tom's answer just said that you *can't* just use Control+L.

Comment: 100% guaranteed? Uninstall Flash. :-P